# Why does attempting to assign a value to a simple type's property in Javascript not throw an exception?

Tags: javascript

Simple types in Javascript are immutable and are not keyed collections like Objects. Why does the following code just return the value of the assignment without complaining?

```
var foo = 'bar';
foo.newProperty = 'blaha';
```

The second statement just returns 'blaha'. However if you now call `foo.newProperty` you naturally get `undefined` because simple types are not hashes. So the question is shouldn't the attempt at property assignment throw an exception the same way that you get a TypeError when trying to replace a value in a tuple in Python. Or is there some obscure feature of the syntax that makes `foo.newProperty` evaluate to something unexpected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an obscure feature of the syntax that makes `foo.newProperty` work. :-) Strings and numbers can be either primitives or objects, and the interpreter will automagically convert from a primitive to an object (and vice-versa) if it sees the need to.

```
var foo = 'bar';              // `foo` is a primitive
alert(typeof foo);            // alerts "string"
var foo2 = new String('bar'); // `foo2` is an object
alert(typeof foo2);           // alerts "object"
```

The reason that adding a property to a primitive works, but then seems later not to have worked, is that the conversion is only for the purposes of the expression. So if I do:

```
foo.newProperty = 'blaha';
```

The primitive string value is retrieved from the `foo` variable and then converted from a primitive to an object for the expression, but *only* for the expression (we haven't assigned a new value to the variable `foo`, after all, it's just that the value retrieved from `foo` for the expression has been changed to make the expression work). If we wanted to ensure that `foo` referred to a `String` *object*, we'd have to do that on purpose:

```
foo = new String(foo);
foo.newProperty = 'blaha';
```

This automagic conversion is covered (a bit) in Section 9 ("Type Conversion and Testing") and Section 11.2.1 ("Property Accessors") in [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), albeit in the usual awkward specification-speak style. :-)

Re your question "...is there a good reason for this automagic wrapping?" below: Oh yes. This automatic promotion from primitive to object is pretty important. For instance:

```
var foo = "bar";
alert(foo.length);
```

Primitives don't have properties, so if there weren't any auto-promotion, the second line above would fail. (Naturally, an implementation is free to optimize such that *actual* object creation isn't required, as long as it behaves as the spec dictates externally.) Similarly:

```
var foo = "bar";
alert(foo.indexOf('a')); // alerts 1
```

Primitives aren't objects, and so they don't have a prototype chain, so where does that `indexOf` property come from? And of course, the answer is that the primitive is promoted to a `String` instance, and `String.prototype` has `indexOf`.

More dramatically:

```
alert((4).toFixed(2)); // alerts "4.00"
```

Since numbers are also promoted as needed, it's perfectly acceptable to do that. You have to use the parens — e.g., the `(4)` rather than just `4` — to satisfy the grammar (since the `.` in a literal number is a decimal point rather than a property accessor), although if you wanted to be *really* esoteric you could use `4['toFixed'](2)`. I wouldn't. :-)

Comment: But why does foo.newProperty return undefined then? Don't you mean that foo should have been automagically converted to an object?

Comment: @Sam: Sorry, I was just adding an explanation of that (needed to look something up).

Comment: The last bit is wrong. You need a `new` to create a `String` object.

Comment: Satisfactory answer, but is there a good reason for this automagic wrapping? It seems to just be confusing.

Comment: @Sam: Good question. And yes, there's a good reason. :-) I've added some comments about it.